# How does this Http.post execute and what is the code path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I'm learning web development and I don't understand how the `Http.post` section works. This is from an [ExpressJS with Typescript repo I found on Github](https://github.com/seanpmaxwell/express-generator-typescript). When the user clicks the login button on the site, this `login.js` script handles click events, right? What exactly is happening when the server does `Http.post('/api/auth/login', data)`? Is `Http` a built-in function in NodeJS? If I look in the directory for this repo, I don't see a `/api/auth/login` folder, so where is this execution going? Ultimately this logs the user in, but I just don't see the code execution path here.

**login.js:**

```
// Login user
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (event.target.matches('#login-btn')) {
    console.log('Login button was pressed')
    logger.info('Login button was pressed')
    var emailInput = document.getElementById('email-input');
    var pwdInput = document.getElementById('pwd-input');
    var data = {
      email: emailInput.value,
      password: pwdInput.value,
    };
    Http
      .post('/api/auth/login', data) // What does this do and how does it do it?
      .then(() => {
        window.location.href = '/users';
      });
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: `document.addEventListener` indicates that is client side code. All else being equal that is going to error because you haven't defined `Http` and browsers don't have  a built in global of that name.

Comment: Searching the repo for *Http* finds the definition of that function without much trouble.

Comment: @Quentin ahh ok yea I found it. It was weird but when I right-clicked it in VSCode and tried to go to its definition, it couldn't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Http is defined in http.js under ./lib/project-files-auth/src/public/scripts

The object is a structure with a `post` attribute associated with a function.

The function is using the standard function `fetch` to send a post request to `'/api/auth/login'`, the call is asynchronous, `fetch` returns a `promise` so you can call `next` and update the window object when the post request has returned something.

Comment: But what is `/api/auth/login`? It's not a directory in this repo, so where is this?

Comment: @TheMortiestMorty it's a URL for some real or hypothetical web-based API

Comment: My bad, I found it - looks like this repo defines these "paths" explicitly under `Paths.ts`